# Prevent dictation from using contact names

Tags: iphone, voice-dictation

I recently added a new contact, Purevbaatar, to my new iPhone.

Now dictation loves transcribing every other word as Purevbaatar, especially in noisy environments. Dictation really writes Purevbaatar a lot, even when it's not remotely similar to what I am actually saying. Even sometimes when I am saying extremely likely phrases, like "hello how are you", it can still type out "Purevbaatar" instead.

Dictation was extremely accurate when the phone was brand new, but it is awful ever since I've started adding contacts.

I would like dictation to not transcribe the names of my contacts at all. So how do I disable the feature?

Comment: Under Settings > General > Keyboards, try turning off the Predictive setting and see if that works.

Comment: @IconDaemon I still see it being typed out almost every other word, but so far in this minute of testing it hasn't been inserted in the end. Not sure whether the behaviour is different from before so I'll keep the setting like this for another day.